# How to make this query correct?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm using this query:

```
=IF(D1=TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IFERROR(QUERY({
IFERROR(QUERY(A4:G,"select A,B,C,'30',E where A is not null and E contains 'Days' or E is null Label '30' '' ",0),{"","","","",""});
IFERROR(QUERY(A4:G,"select A,B,C,'60',F where A is not null and F contains 'Days' or F is null Label '60' '' ",0),{"","","","",""});
IFERROR(QUERY(A4:G,"select A,B,C,'90',G where A is not null and G contains 'Days' or G is null Label '90' '' ",0),{"","","","",""})},
"Select * where Col1 is not null",0),""), 
VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(IFERROR(QUERY({
IFERROR(QUERY(A4:G,"select A,B,C,'30',E where A is not null and E contains 'Days' or E is null Label '30' '' ",0),{"","","","",""});
IFERROR(QUERY(A4:G,"select A,B,C,'60',F where A is not null and F contains 'Days' or F is null Label '60' '' ",0),{"","","","",""});
IFERROR(QUERY(A4:G,"select A,B,C,'90',G where A is not null and G contains 'Days' or G is null Label '90' '' ",0),{"","","","",""})},
"Select Col5 where Col1 is not null",0),""),"\d+"))}, "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 where Col6 <=10 order by Col6")),""
)
```

[image]

My problem is that the first line (Cell I4 ) is duplicating the content instead of having it in 2 rows

How to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try perhaps:

```
=IF(D1=TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IFERROR(QUERY({
IFERROR(QUERY(A4:G,"select A,B,C,'30',E where A is not null and E contains 'Days' or E is null Label '30' '' ",0),{"","","","",""});
IFERROR(QUERY(A4:G,"select A,B,C,'60',F where A is not null and F contains 'Days' or F is null Label '60' '' ",0),{"","","","",""});
IFERROR(QUERY(A4:G,"select A,B,C,'90',G where A is not null and G contains 'Days' or G is null Label '90' '' ",0),{"","","","",""})},
"Select * where Col1 is not null",0),""), 
VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(IFERROR(QUERY({
IFERROR(QUERY(A4:G,"select A,B,C,'30',E where A is not null and E contains 'Days' or E is null Label '30' '' ",0),{"","","","",""});
IFERROR(QUERY(A4:G,"select A,B,C,'60',F where A is not null and F contains 'Days' or F is null Label '60' '' ",0),{"","","","",""});
IFERROR(QUERY(A4:G,"select A,B,C,'90',G where A is not null and G contains 'Days' or G is null Label '90' '' ",0),{"","","","",""})},
"Select Col5 where Col1 is not null",0),""),"\d+"))}, "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 where Col6 <=10 order by Col6", 0)),""
)
```